# Extend class that uses a nested callback style and write new class using async await?

Tags: node.js, async-await

Can I extend classes that uses a nested callback style and write the child class using async await? Will there be issues?

Working with legacy code but would rather work in async await style to get this done quickly since that's what I know.

Comment: What do you mean by "class that uses callbacks"? It all depends on *how* it uses callbacks.

Comment: Sorry, nested callback style is what I meant.

Comment: If you don't want to violate the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), you probably won't have much choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.
There should not be issues at all - you can built-in apis like [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)
Initially all callbacks could be converted to promises in this style:

```
const promise = () => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   doStuff((err, data) => {
     if (err) reject(err);
     else resolve(data);
   })
 })
}

await promise();
```

Comment: Sweet, that'll work, thanks!